# When to use AsyncSession in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, fastapi

The SQLAlchemy docs are quite difficult to understand so I am hoping someone who knows this ORM could explain:

When am I meant to use the [async extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html) of SQLAlchemy along with its
AsyncSession, as opposed to the regular synchronous Session?

Is it needed to build any real backend to serve many clients in production?

My context is that I am building a web backend with FastAPI for our organization. I first thought the async extension was so that the framework could handle multiple requests concurrently if say a database operation took a long time. But I tried calling the two routes below, A then B right after, thinking that not using anything async they would be handled synchronously.

```
from time import sleep
from fastapi import  FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/A")
def A():
    print("serving A")
    sleep(5) # simulated long DB operation
    print("Done: A")
    return


@app.get("/B")
def B():
    print("Done: B")
    return
```

But after requesting the two routes with the Swagger included in FastAPI, it prints

```
serving A
Done: B
INFO:     127.0.0.1:54893 - "GET /B HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done: A
INFO:     127.0.0.1:54891 - "GET /A HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Since the framework can handle requests concurrently, the reason for using async SQLAlchemy and AsyncSession cannot be that otherwise your DB dependent requests would be handled synchronously.

Since using the async extension seems to bring difficulties (like [M1 installation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#asyncio-platform-installation-notes-including-apple-m1), [preventing implicit IO](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#preventing-implicit-io-when-using-asyncsession) and losing the legacy Query API), I'd prefer not to unless there's some huge advantage that I'm not seeing.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75463993/2144390

Answer (score 1):

have you considered this case?

```
@app.get("/A")
    def A():
        print("serving A")
        sleep(5) # simulated long DB operation
        sleep(5) # simulated long DB operation
        print("Done: A")
        return
```

these two "sleeps" can be executed asynchronously, cutting the entire route's runtime in half in the best case.